# Spring Java Configuration: Create Bean From Dynamic Class Name

Tags: spring, configuration, dependency-injection

My situation is that the class name of a bean can be configured by an external properties-file. It's fine to do this with XML

```
  <bean id="myService" class="${app.serviceClass}" />
```

and properties-file

```
app.serviceClass=com.example.GreatestClassThereIs
```

I tried to convert it to Java using a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

  @Value("${app.serviceClass}")
  private String serviceClassName;

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    logger.warn("let's register bean of class " + serviceClassName + "...");
    GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(serviceClassName);

    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
    registry.registerBeanDefinition("myService", beanDefinition);
    logger.warn("done " + beanDefinition);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the lifecycle of Spring hasn't yet set handled the `@Value` and `serviceClassName` is `null`. How do I get the property in there?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. You have a `@Configuration` class which is actually a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. Seems strange to me. Defining a `@Bean` and use the Spring `ClassUtils` to create an instance of that bean. Else registering a `RootBeanDefinition` with `${app.serviceClass}` might also work.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, the source in my question is just the important stuff for this question. I don't want to write off-topic stuff that may cause more confusion. I will check your two suggestions. Would both cause Spring to do DI and such on the bean?

Comment: A bean is a bean no matter how it is constructed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I completely fail to understand what the supposedly duplicate question is about. I can see that an answer suggests to use `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`, which I haven't heard of yet, but the rest is so confusing I can't even argue whether or not my question is a duplicate ;)

Comment: Nevermind, I was way off. Sorry and reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply define a new `Bean` in your `ApplicationContext` by using `Class.forName()` from the `@Value` injected into the `@Configuration`?

So something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration
{

     @Value("${app.serviceClass}")
     private String serviceClassName;

     @Bean
     public Object myService()
     {
          return Class.forName(serviceClassName).newInstance();
     }
}
```

---

EDIT by sjngm (for better readability than in the comment):

```
     @Bean
     public MyInterface myService()
     {
        Class<?> serviceClass = Class.forName(serviceClassName);
        MyInterface service = MyInterface.class.cast(serviceClass.newInstance());
        return service;
     }
```

Comment: I guess that when implementing against interfaces the return type of `myService` can be the interface. This is important for DI of this bean in other places.

Comment: How do we implement this if we do not have serviceClassName during application startup?